# devise skip_confirmation! is still sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

I am using devise and I want to skip confirmation email. Despite, I am using skip_confirmation! before user.save, it is still sending email. This is really maddening as I have tried so many ways but skip_confirmation! is not working at all.

```
u = User.new(:email => "abc@example.com", :password => "12345678")
u.skip_confirmation!
u.save
```

Comment: Please put the code you're using as it is.

Comment: code added please check

Comment: Have u restarted your server..

Comment: this I am doing in rails console

Answer (score 1):

The code shown above worked for me, but I was having the same problems when I was using the User.create() method:

```
u = User.create(:email => "abc@example.com", :password => "12345678")
u.skip_confirmation!
u.save
```

`User.create()` automatically sends the emails before the `skip_confirmation!` can work. Make sure to use `User.new()`.